# Error in connecting to a local SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

```
//SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection( "Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.Combine( Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location ), "DBThree.sdf" ) );

//SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection( @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DBThree.sdf" );

//SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection( ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBThreeConnectionString"].ConnectionString );

SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection( @"Data Source=""C:\Users\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ForTesting2\ForTesting2\DBThree.sdf""" ); 
con.Open();

string comnd = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Mytable";
SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand( comnd, con );

string test1 = com1.ExecuteScalar().ToString() ;
label1.Text = "AAA\t" + test1;
con.Close();
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 23,Token in error = Mytable ]

I also tried the connection strings which are commented in above code. The connection string in `app.config` looks like

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBThreeConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DBThree.sdf"
         providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I am new to database, so where I can find this edit delete flag?

Comment: Hello Grant, Thanks for solution. I spelled it correctly but the square bracket did the trick. I still don't know why it worked in that way.